# oracle handling insert before delete statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-insert, sql-delete

What is the best approach to handle inserting data before deleting it, how can i make sure that after i insert data from table1 to table2 i wont lose any if i want to delete the data i inserted from table1.

I'm working on a procedure and so far i came up with this process, which im not sure is the best way to secure the data i insert.

```
SAVEPOINT start_transaction;
           stmt_ins:= 'INSERT into ' || n_tab2 || ' SELECT * FROM ' || n_tab || ' where criado_em< :dt';  
           EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt_ins USING sysdate;
           dbms_output.put_line('value '||SQL%ROWCOUNT);
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(stmt_ins);
         --  siima_logs_bck.INSE_LOG(1,'TESTE INSERIR','INS_LOGS','2', 'testes insert log');

EXCEPTION 
           WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
           ROLLBACK TO start_transaction;


                   stmt_del:= 'DELETE FROM ' || n_tab || ' WHERE criado_em<:dt';

         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(stmt_del);
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt_del USING SYSDATE;
```

Basically i get the data from tab1 insert into tab2 acording to its creation date. what can i do to try to not fail my insert and lose the data i delete?

any tips/guide that would help improve my process is appreciated, thank you

Comment: I don't understand your logic - if you want the insert and delete to be atomic (so if the insert fails you *don't* delete), then why have you put the delete in the exception handler? Surely you want it before, so if either statement fails the exceptions can be caught and both statements (if it reached and failed on the delete) can be rolled back together; and if the insert fails it doesn't try to delete at all?

Comment: thats what i need help with, dont know how to structure it properly so if it fails in any of those cases i rollback

Comment: You could add to your DELETE statement a WHERE clause that checks for the existence of the record in TABLE2? e.g. 

    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ...)

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/exists.php

Comment: Are you saying that if you insert rows from table 1 to table 2 and there's an error, you want all the rows you added from table 1 to be rolled back, and none of the table 2 rows that were already there to be deleted? If so, the rollback will take care of that.

Comment: @Boneist id prefer if it fails 1 row it does not delete that row, but i can probably live with it all being rolled back

Comment: @Sapo121 I'm still not sure what you mean. If a row errors, it doesn't get inserted so it can't be deleted anyway. Are you saying that you'd prefer all the other rows inserted by that insert statement from table 1 into table 2 not get rolled back in the event of an error? If so, that's not possible. If I were you, I'd use a MERGE statement to insert the rows only if they don't exist in table 2, joining on table 2's unique columns. That way, you won't ever get the dup_val_on_index error.

Comment: @Boneist so the way i have it structured right now if the insert fails (i will put the delete statement before the exception handler) it will rollback? canceling everything?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do? Insert all rows from table 1 that meet the criteria into table 2 (where they don't already exist) and then delete rows from table 1 that are in table 2? If so, you can probably do all of that in a single merge statement. It would help if you could edit your question to include some sample data for your tables 1 and 2, along with what you expect to see in both tables after the procedure has run.

Comment: problem with the merge is i need unique keys, and i dont have them, since my tables are dynamic, i get my tables from rows in another table, i dont know if im being clear trying to explain.

I have table A with a list of tables and table B with a list of the backups of those tables .

i just dont want to risk losing data, when inserting and deleting from table1 one to table2.